# Wrong gitosis config. I'm locked out the server

Tags: centos, ssh, git

I made a stupid mistake. I have a small vhosted CentOS server and I was configuring git+gitosis when i think I ran the gitosis ssh key init on my own user in addition to the git user. I didn't realize it at the time but now when i try to ssh to the server with my user i get:

```
TY allocation request failed on channel 0
ERROR:gitosis.serve.main:Need SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND in environment.
Connection to [servernamehere] closed.
```

Any idea how I can login to the server again? Unfortunately i have disabled ssh root login.
Thanks!

A more complete log (relevant part):

```
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug2: callback start
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 100 id 0
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd ext data 67
ERROR:gitosis.serve.main:Need SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND in environment.
debug2: channel 0: written 67 to efd 7
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: close_write
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug2: channel 0: close_read
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
#0 client-session (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 fd -1/-1 cfd -1)
debug3: channel 0: close_fds r -1 w -1 e 7 c -1
Connection to myserver closed.
```

Comment: Who are you hosted with? Most hosts of virtual machines allow console access using their administration panel.

Comment: @dannymcc Unfortunately my provider does not. They might do it internally if I contact their support. I was asking to see if there's an easy solution as it seems that the connection is established (via publickey) but then killed by gitosis.

Comment: Is the connection killed as soon as you run a git command?

Comment: @dannymcc  i don't run any git command. git works fine on the git@server, but when i try to simply connect to myuser@server that's when it gets disconnected. if i run ssh -v -v -v myuser@server i see the log that i just added in description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry Cristian no easy answer to this, your user can only interact with git.

Comment: Yup. Seems you're right. Fortunately the vps provider was kind enough to reset my sshd config file to allow root login. Any idea what i must do to remove the gitosis hook?

Comment: Found the solution. You need to edit .ssh/authorized_keys to remove the command added by gitosis to auto-execute on ssh login.

Comment: Ah congrats on regaining control ;)